# How to add event in FSCalendar in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, calendar, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar for application purpose. The FSCalendar demo is below.

https://github.com/MarcBruins/FSCalendar-Xamarin-iOS

I try to search on SO and Google from 2 days. But I coundn't find a way to how to add event in FSCalendar.

It would pleasure if someone use this and help me to how to add event in FSCalendar.

Any Help be Appreciated.

**Edit :**

[image]

look this Image

When I click on Date 15 the event of the Date 15 is show below the calender.  `Hey Daily Event` place. I Hope now you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events in `FSCalendar` are supplied via a `DataSource`, much like other datasource-based controls (i.e.`UITableView`).

This example subclasses `FSCalendarDataSource` and added a hard-coded list of event dates (normally you would set/retrieve those via SQLite, Realm, etc...)

```
public class CalendarDataSource : FSCalendarDataSource
{
    NSCalendarUnit calenderUnits = NSCalendarUnit.Year | NSCalendarUnit.Month | NSCalendarUnit.Day;
    NSCalendar calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
    List<NSDate> events;

    public CalendarDataSource()
    {
        events = new List<NSDate>();
        events.Add(NSDate.Now);
        events.Add(calendar.DateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, 3, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None));
        events.Add(calendar.DateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, 5, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None));
        events.Add(calendar.DateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, 7, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None));
        events.Add(calendar.DateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, 9, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None));
    }

    bool SameDate(NSDate date1, NSDate date2)
    {
        return NSComparisonResult.Same == calendar.CompareDate(date1, date2, calenderUnits);
    }

    [Export("calendar:hasEventForDate:")]
    public override bool HasEventForDate(FSCalendar calendar, NSDate date)
    {
        return events.Any((NSDate eventDate) => (SameDate(eventDate, date)));
    }

    public override nint NumberOfEventsForDate(FSCalendar calendar, NSDate date)
    {
        return events.Any((NSDate eventDate) => (SameDate(eventDate, date))) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Then instance the datasource and assign it to your calendar instance:

```
calender = new FSCalendar
{
    Frame = View.Frame,
    DataSource = new CalendarDataSource()
};
```

Comment: @SushilHangover Thanks the binding working fine but i want to show the event below by calendar so that i can see this particular date i have this event.

Comment: @Ironman The FSCalendarDataSource in my example adds 5 events to the calendar, they will be denoted by a dot under the day's date.

Comment: A dot under the day's date fine. But when I click that dot i want to show the event below my tableview bind up. So That i can know my this date I have this event. See my edit.

Comment: @Ironman That is a different question then you asked, the `FSCalendarDelegate` handles functions like `DidSelectDate`